# .live is not a function error

Tags: jquery

I'm using some jquery to hide list elements when a page is loaded. When the code is static, it works fine, but the list elements are being generated dynamically via php and aren't all available when the page is loaded. I've tried to attach the .hide to the load event, but get the error,

> $('li.views-row').live is not a function.

Code is all at http://jsfiddle.net/Ypqyv/, although because the html there already exists when you hit Run you can't see the error. (No, I cannot post a link to the actual site; it's on a dev server behind a firewall.)

Any ideas? I've read a whole bunch of answers here about issues with .live(), but none of them seem to apply to my situation.

ETA: using jquery 1.6.

Comment: Not getting any errors. Does your fiddle represent the actual situation?

Comment: As much as it can; as I said - the list items in the live code are generated by php, so there's really no way that jsfiddle can give you the exact situation.

Comment: Can't you simulate the list items being added later in the Fiddle somehow? A demonstration of a bug that isn't really broken doesn't help with diagnosing the issue.

Comment: `.live` with the load event only works for images. Maybe even if you did get rid of the error, it still wont throw an event on the `load` event of an `li` because an `li` doesn't throw one.

Comment: @KevinB - can you show me documentation that says that? I didn't see anything to that effect.

Comment: It's native javascript. the `load` event only happens for elements that have a `src` attribute and the `window` object, and, the load event on an iframe does not properly bubble and therefore can't be bound to with `.live()`. You can probably find official documentation on that at the mozilla site or w3schools.com.

Comment: Here's the w3schools reference: http://w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp - And, for a reference to the iframe not properly bubbling it's load event, it can be found on this page: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @Inerdial - I just added a button that will add another list item when clicked. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @KevinB - thanks for the reference, although I don't understand what iframes have to do with anything. I'm not using iframes anywhere.

Comment: It's just an exception. In your case, there isn't an event you can bind to that will help you in this situation. You need to instead use the success, done, or always callback of the ajax request to manipulate the list items. Similar to this fiddle, note the added `.hide()` http://jsfiddle.net/Ypqyv/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting the error `.live is not a function error`, however, `.live` will not work in this situation anyway.

`<li>` elements do not fire off an `onload` when they are created, therefore a `$("li").live("load",handler)` will never get triggered anyway.
http://w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Instead, you should manipulate the list item right after the code that adds it to the page.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "...",
  data: "...",
  type: "...",
  success: function(data){
    $("<li>"+data+"</li>").hide().appendTo("#myul");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of JQuery that you are using, .live() is only available with versions 1.3 - 1.8 (deprecated in 1.8) I believe and has been removed from version 1.9

Comment: If you had read the entire OP, you'd see that it stated we were using 1.6, which does have `.live()` available.